# Container/structure of + plural noun → singular or plural noun + container/structure? (i.e. “tree of folders” → “folder tree” or “folders tree”)

Tags: singular-vs-plural

What convention should I use and why?

| container/structure + of + plural noun | singular noun + container/structure | plural noun + container/structure |
| --- | --- | --- |
| tree of folders | folder tree | folders tree |
| table of colors | color table | colors table |
| table of users | user table | users table |
| table of products | product table | products table |
| bag of apples | apple bag | apples bag |
| basket of grapes | grape basket | grapes basket |
| cart of commodities | commodity cart | commodities cart |
| list of ingredients | ingredient list | ingredients list |
| dictionary of words | word dictionary | words dictionary |
| dict of Python objects | Python object dict | Python objects dict |
| ***** tree of types | type tree | types tree |
| ***** tree of classes | class tree | classes tree |
| set of elements | element set | elements set |
| list of attributes | attribute list | attributes list |
| list of properties | property list | properties list |

[*] We can call it a tree when we assume that each considered type/class has a single parent (direct base) type/class.

Grammar in the left column is obvious so it doesn't need any explanation. The problem is in choosing between the middle and the right column. Which of them presents the proper grammar? “Plural noun + container/structure” (as in the right column) seems to be more logical to me but much more often I encounter the “singular noun + container/structure” grammar. Can you explain it?

What phrase can I to google to read more about the matter.

#### EDIT

Thank you, @[banuyayi](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/161437/banuyayi) for the answer!

OK, you said:

> it may be that the use of list/cart/bag/tree makes **the use of the plural almost redundant**.

This is the opposite to what I thought before. In my view, the “ingredient list” == “list of ingredient” (one ingredient) which is nonsensical because, from the nature of list, it is a container/box for multiple items, even if the particular list currently consists of only one item (before we add more items to it). I feel it (the use of singular noun in such a context) as contradictory to logic.

Maybe I am wrong. Does your statement mean that I should treat the **noun before** list/table/box/bag/cart/basket as a some sort of **adjective** describing feature/property/quality/trait of the noun after it?

Are there cases when we can't interpret it as an adjective?

Take, for example, the following description of the simple Python program as a context for my next question:

> The function Factory() takes the table (list of tuples) of various food types (its names and properties). It then returns a *dict of food types (classes)* dynamically created from the metaclass Food.
> You can then use the dict as follows:

```
my_delicious_strawberry = FoodTypes['strawberry'](size=5, color='light red')
my_delicious_strawberry.ripen()
print(my_delicious_strawberry.color)  # prints: dark red
characters['Eva'].eat(my_delicious_strawberry)

my_delicious_mango = FoodTypes['mango'](size=41, color='red and yellow')
characters['Adam'].peel_fruit(my_delicious_mango)
print(my_delicious_mango.state)  # print: peeled

characters['Lilith'].eat(my_delicious_mango)
print(my_delicious_mango.state)  # print: eaten
```

From the above context we can know that FoodTypes is a dict (some sort of collection of named items) containing the defined classes of food (stored somewhere in the database and then dynamically restored into progam namespace).

We can write it more generally as:

> The function Factory() returns a **dict of types**.

We can also write this as:

> The function Factory() produces a **types dict**.

... or:

> The function Factory() produces a **type dict**.

How can we read this?

- **types dict** — we can read this as “dictionary (map) of types”
- **type dict** — we can misinterpret this as “type named "dict" ”

Correct me if I'm wrong, please.

Additionally, are you sure we should say:

> list **for** ingredients

instead of:

> list **of** ingredients?

The Google Books Ngram Viewer [says the opposite](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=list+for+ingredients%2Clist+of+ingredients).

Comment: Hello and welcome to ELL. On this site we expect people asking questions to do some minimal amount of research before asking. Did you search both forms of, say, "color table" and "colors table" to see which is more common? Do that for several of the items in the list and I think you'll find the answer yourself

Comment: @gotube: “Did you search both forms of, say, "color table" and "colors table" to see which is more common?” Yes, I did. For me, it is a waste of time to ask questions anywhere on the internet (forums, QA sites, etc.) because almost always someone had the same problem before me. It is unlikely to be the first, so I can read solved problems. Unfortunately, in this case, Google tells me only the number of pages instead of the grammatical rule.

Comment: I stand corrected. "List of" is more common than "list for". As for "type dict", all I can say is, "we have to  live with the ambiguity". "List for" is used when the list is for some purpose, e.g." She is on the short list for the Nobel Prize". In your big list the last item "list of properties"; if a person has many properties we generally say "property list", and in the office of a real estate agent "the list of properties" may be called "properties list" or "property list". In case of properties of a thing, we are more likely to say "property list".

Comment: Thanks a lot, @banuyayi! “In case of properties of a thing, we are more likely to say "property list"”. This is my case (a list of properties of some object in a memory operated by some computer program). “As for "type dict" [...] we have to live with the ambiguity”. This one is the root cause I asked the question, so I'm unhappy with this statement. Never mind, I'll probably stay with the “dict of types” in the description of the factory function (not the one from the above code — this one is fictional, fabricated ad hoc as an example).

Comment: By the way, I've done a lot of additional research and now I know that the best keywords to google with are: [attributive noun adjunct modifier singular plural](https://www.google.com/search?q=attributive+noun+adjunct+modifier+singular+plural).

Comment: Kudos. Your case  has been posted  for appraisal as regards the possibility of absolving you of the alleged crime of not doing proper research. The case is now listed in the court of superior ministry of Lexicultists. Jokes apart, the use of the plural in the attributive noun is increasing as is seen in the results of your google search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Mostly it is idiomatic.

By way of an attempt at explanation, it may be that the use of list/cart/bag/tree makes the use of the plural almost redundant.

A list presumably contains a multitude of items. Similarly bag, cart, tree can contain many things.

We do not say "list of an ingredient".

"A list? Of what?" We have to specify what items are listed in the list. We say "List of ingredients".

When the order is reversed, we have already specified what items are listed in the list, so there is no need for using the plural for the "items". It is presumed that it would be in multitude.